How to Read Telemetry via S.Port Using M5Stick and Happymodel ELRS ES24TX Pro
I am working on a project where I am using the Happymodel ELRS ES24TX Pro 2.4GHz TX and M5StickC to receive and process telemetry through the S.Port protocol.
The main goal is to read telemetry from the flight controller connected to the ELRS receiver and display this data on the M5StickC screen, as well as in the Serial Monitor. Currently, I am using M5StickC to send RC commands via CRSF to the ELRS receiver, and that part works successfully. However, I would like to add the ability to read telemetry coming from the flight controller via S.Port, and I am having difficulties with this.
My Current Setup:
Transmitter: Happymodel ELRS ES24TX Pro 2.4GHz TX.

Microcontroller: M5StickC (ESP32).

Using the CRSF library to send RC data, and I want to use the same or a new library to receive telemetry.

Problem:
I know that S.Port is used for simultaneous channel data transmission and telemetry.

At the moment, I am successfully transmitting RC packets to the receiver, but I can't figure out how to properly read the telemetry data.

My goal is to understand how to correctly switch to receiving telemetry data and how to work with the data stream from S.Port.

I have also tried using a timer and switching between sending and receiving data, but the receiver still does not see a stable connection, and the telemetry is either absent or comes in an incorrect format.
Questions:
Are there any recommendations or examples on how to properly read telemetry via S.Port using M5Stick and Happymodel ELRS?
How should the RX/TX pins be configured for using S.Port on ELRS?
Do I need to additionally process or modify the CRSF packets to correctly receive telemetry?
#include "CRSF.h"
#include "M5StickCPlus2.h"




#define CRSFinterval 50
#define uartCRSFinverted false

const int ledPin = 19;
const int rxPin = 26;

CRSF crsf;

#define CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN 172
#define CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MID 992
#define CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MAX 1811

hw_timer_t *timer = NULL;
portMUX_TYPE timerMux = portMUX_INITIALIZER_UNLOCKED;
volatile bool printFlag = false;

void printPacketHex(uint8_t *packet, size_t length) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (packet[i] < 0x10) {
      Serial.print("0");
    }
    Serial.print(packet[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void IRAM_ATTR onTimer() {
  portENTER_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
  crsf.sendRCFrameToFC();
  printFlag = true;
  portEXIT_CRITICAL_ISR(&timerMux);
}

void StartTimer() {
  timer = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
  timerAttachInterrupt(timer, &onTimer, true);
  timerAlarmWrite(timer, CRSFinterval * 80, true);
  timerAlarmEnable(timer);
}




void setup() {
  M5.begin();
  M5.Lcd.fillScreen(BLACK);
  M5.Lcd.setTextColor(WHITE);
  M5.Lcd.setTextSize(1.5);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, rxPin, -1);
  
  if (Serial1) {
    Serial.println("Serial1 initialized successfully.");
    M5.Lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    M5.Lcd.println("Serial1 initialized.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error initializing Serial1.");
    M5.Lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    M5.Lcd.println("Serial1 init error.");
  }

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  crsf.Begin();
  
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch0 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch1 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch2 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch3 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch4 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch5 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch6 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch7 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch8 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch9 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch10 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch11 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch12 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch13 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch14 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch15 = CRSF_CHANNEL_VALUE_MIN;
  
  crsf.sendRCFrameToFC();
  
  StartTimer();
}

void loop() {
  if (printFlag) {
    printFlag = false;
    
    M5.Lcd.fillScreen(BLACK);
    M5.Lcd.setCursor(1, 1);
    M5.Lcd.setTextColor(WHITE);
    M5.Lcd.println("CRSF packet:");
    M5.Lcd.setTextColor(GREEN);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(crsf.PackedRCdataOut); i++) {
      if (((uint8_t *)&crsf.PackedRCdataOut)[i] < 0x10) {
        M5.Lcd.print("0");
      }
      M5.Lcd.print(((uint8_t *)&crsf.PackedRCdataOut)[i], HEX);
      M5.Lcd.print(" ");
    }
    M5.Lcd.println();
  }

  if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 85);
    M5.Lcd.setTextColor(YELLOW);
    M5.Lcd.setTextSize(1);
    M5.Lcd.println("Incoming data:");

    if (Serial1.available() >= 32) {
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch0 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch1 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch2 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch3 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch4 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch5 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch6 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch7 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch8 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch9 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch10 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch11 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch12 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch13 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch14 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);
      crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch15 = Serial1.read() | (Serial1.read() << 8);

      for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        uint16_t channelValue;
        switch (i) {
          case 0: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch0; break;
          case 1: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch1; break;
          case 2: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch2; break;
          case 3: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch3; break;
          case 4: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch4; break;
          case 5: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch5; break;
          case 6: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch6; break;
          case 7: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch7; break;
          case 8: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch8; break;
          case 9: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch9; break;
          case 10: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch10; break;
          case 11: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch11; break;
          case 12: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch12; break;
          case 13: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch13; break;
          case 14: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch14; break;
          case 15: channelValue = crsf.PackedRCdataOut.ch15; break;
        }

        M5.Lcd.print("CH"); M5.Lcd.print(i); M5.Lcd.print(": ");
        M5.Lcd.println(channelValue);

        Serial.print("CH"); Serial.print(i); Serial.print(": ");
        Serial.println(channelValue);
      }
      crsf.sendRCFrameToFC();
    } else {
      M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 85);
      M5.Lcd.setTextColor(RED);
      M5.Lcd.println("Not enough data to read.");
      Serial.println("Not enough data to read.");
    }
  } else {
    M5.Lcd.setCursor(10, 85);
    M5.Lcd.setTextColor(RED);
    M5.Lcd.println("No data on Serial1.");
    Serial.println("No data on Serial1.");
  }

  delay(100);
}


